# Grouping content in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql database:

[image]

I would like to group the messages based on the t0_id (4) and the from_id.
The messages should be in groups of different from_id based on to_id of 4

```
That is get a php output of:
1. get: TRUELOVE, hadi when(from_id is 1)
2. get: cutie (from_id 2)
3. get: true love(from_id 3)
```

NB: THE FROM_ID IS NOT CONSTANT VALUE BUT to_id IS CONSTANT (4)

How can i write the sql statement

Comment: Your picture looks more like `mysql`, please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sorry HoneyBadger yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use group_concat for mysql

```
 select group_concat(messg)
 from my_table 
 where to_id = 4
 group by from_id;
```

Comment: How can i output it in php such that i can see the messages in groups

Comment: Thats true ill ask the another question

Comment: Thats the question link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985899/outputting-data-in-php-from-sql