# Outputting data in php from sql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to output grouped data from mysql in php

The sql database:
[image]

I have an sql statement that groups the content according to a to_id of 4.

```
sql statement: select group_concat(messg) from my_table  where to_id = 4   
group by from_id;
```

I would like to view the messages in php such that i get:

```
1. get: 2messages  from_id 1(messages: TRUELOVE, hadi when)
2. get: 1 msg from_id 2(message: cutie)
3. get: 1 msg from_id 3(message: true love)
```

STATEMENTS TO CONNECT TO DATABASE:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","bmcs" );

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

  echo "Failed to connect to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: What do you use for accessing msqyl by php ?

Comment: Am using JQUERY JSON via ajax requests which outputs content to html

Comment: Are you getting some result with your query?

Comment: This is for ajax in client but for php in server how do you are connect to mysql ..

Comment: You use msqli or pdo or a framework?

Comment: I use mysqli..Ill update the question to show the connection

Comment: I have updated question with the database connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with mysqli shoudl be this code

```
  <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT 
            group_concat(messg) as msg, from_id, time_sent
            from my_table 
            where to_id = 4   
            group by from_id"; 

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
            while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
                echo $obj->msg . '<br />'; 
                echo $obj->from_id . '<br />'; 
                echo $obj->time_sent. '<br />'; 


            } 
        } 
        $result->close(); 
        unset($obj); 
        unset($sql); 
        unset($query); 

?>
```

Comment: I have tried and the code works. Could you modify the code to show from_id and time values as it only shows the message alone when concatenated

Comment: Please if free check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990138/outputting-concatenated-data-from-mysql-to-json-as-json-object

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI  seems you don't have acceppted my answer .. why?