# Outputting concatenated data from mysql to json as json object

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my database:

[image]

Am trying to get all from_id which to_id is 4 to a json object where ill be able to show all messages from a from_id in a stack sorted by their different time_sent

I have tried:

CODE:
DATABASE  QUERY CLASS(THIS IS IN THE DBASE CLASS)

```
public function query($sql){    

 $this->_last_query = $sql;
 $result = mysqli_query($this->_conndb, $sql);
 $this->displayQuery($result);
 return $result;    

} // end of query

public function displayQuery($result){
if(!$result){
    $output = "database query failed :". mysqli_error($this->_conndb);
    $output .= "last sql query was: ".$this->_last_query;
    die($output);       
    }   
    else{
        $this->_affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->_conndb);

        }
} //End of query results

public function fetchAll($sql){
    
    $result =  $this->query($sql);
    $out =  array();
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $out[] =  $row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return $out;
}
```

MESSAGE CLASS:

```
private $_table = 'messages';
public function getadminMessage(){
     $sql = "SELECT group_concat(messg, time_sent, from_id) as from_id from {$this->_table} where to_id = 4 group by from_id"; 
    return $this->db->fetchAll($sql);//IN THE DBASE CLASS ABOVE
    
    }
```

In the file getadminmessage.php

```
    $message = new Message();
$results  = $message-> getadminMessage();
echo json_encode($results);
```

I then use getjson

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/tum_old/custom/php/getadminmsg.php",

function(response){
console.log(response);

});
```

On my log i get

[image]

The data seems group concatenated but i would also like the various messages to be in object form that is the messages to be displayed as objects such that i can easily do:

data.object[0].from_id[0].msg to get TRUE LOVE as the message

## scais::::

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you are grouping your query result? You probably could just use the result plus all those columns in an associative array. Also, make sure you output a json formatted string (http://php.net/json_encode)

Comment: am actually developing a chat app. In this code its where a user can get messages from different people and a single person can send multiple messages. So by grouping them a user can be able to view multiple messages under one bundle.....Could you be more clear on using of the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for select you need

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(messg) as msg, time_sent, from_id
  from {$this->_table} where to_id = 4 group by from_id";
```

for server side you  need json_encode  the array

```
public function fetchAll($sql){

  $result =  $this->query($sql);
  $out =  array();
  $cnt =0;
  while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $out[$cnt]['msg'] =  $row['msg'];
    $out[$cnt]['time_sent'] =  $row['time_sent'];
    $out[$cnt]['from_id'] =  $row['from_id'];

    $cnt++;
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  return json_encode($out);
}
```

Comment: am getting an error of unable to get property of non object.. Let me update the question with the full connection and query class

Comment: I have update the answer ( fetch_assoc return array and not object ..)

Comment: Am now getting an error of undefined index(msg, form_id, time_sent)

Comment: After changing am getting error of undefined offsets(0,1,2)

Comment: I have update the asnwer with the correct select  ..and loop for render

Comment: Still the same this is the error .... of (<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: from_id in <b>C:\wamp\www\tum_old\classes\dbase.php</b> on line <b>114</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: from_id in <b>C:\wamp\www\tum_old\classes\dbase.php</b> on line <b>114</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: from_id in <b>C:\wamp\www\tum_old\classes\dbase.php</b> on line <b>114</b><br />)

Comment: I have forget  the from_id in select .. now i have added .. i have update the answer .. the select part ..

Comment: This works but the messages are put all together . Is there a way they can be separated as objects ..Or if not possible get their count..Ill update the question with the image of the log

Comment: Ok i have added the encode for  json .. i have update the answer .. but for tonight .. i take a break  .. comment me tomorrow ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   public function fetchAll($sql){

    $result =  $this->query($sql);
    $out =  array();
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $out[] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'from_id' => $row['from_id'],
            'to_id' => $row['to_id'],
            'msg' => $row['messg']
        );
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    return json_encode($out);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the group by statement and building a new multi dimensional array instead with the result rows before you output it as a json encoded string. See example below

```
$out = array(
    'messages' => array(),
);
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $out['messages'][$b['from_id']][] = array(
        'msg' => $b['message'],
        'time_sent' => $b['time_sent'],
    );
}
return $out;
```

The keys in your $out['messages'] array will be your from_id values. Each entry will be arrays of messages from each id, so in your javascript you should be able to iterate over these